# Receiving an error when calling a public class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Here's the error:

> An object reference is required for a non-static field, method, or
>   property 'ArchiCapture.Models.dbConnection.runSproc(string[],
>   string[], string)'

It appears at the call dt = dbConnection.runSproc(paramName, paramValue, "pr_select_employee_by_id");

I'm trying to develop a class that will call SPROCs.  Here's my class.

```
namespace ArchiCapture.Models
{
    public class dbConnection
    {

    public DataTable runSproc(string[] paramName, string[] paramValue, string sproc)
    {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader reader = null;

            try
            {
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AC2012"].ConnectionString;
                using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sproc, conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    for (int x = 0; x < paramName.Count(); x++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(paramName[x], paramValue[x]));
                    }
                    conn.Open();

                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);

                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        } 
    }
}
}
```

And here's how I'm calling it..

```
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string[] paramName = new string[1] { "@employee_id" };
                string[] paramValue = new string[1] { searchEngine.Value };


                dt = dbConnection.runSproc(paramName, paramValue, "pr_select_employee_by_id");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016437/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Comment: Please do not name classes starting with lowercase letter for public samples. Following [C# coding guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) makes code easier to read for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a `static` method:

```
public static DataTable runSproc(string[] paramName, string[] paramValue, string sproc)
```

Or, as the error message states, you must instantiate a new instance of your class before calling an instance method:

```
dbConnection conn = new dbConnection();
dt = conn.runSproc(paramName, paramValue, "pr_select_employee_by_id");
```

Also, generally class names are PascalCased. Consider `DbConnection` instead of `dbConnection`.